# Exchange 2010 OWA redirect to Exchange 2003 login issues

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

We have just installed an Exchange 2010 CAS server.  Instead of moving everything and renaming and adding certificates, we merely added the CAS as a totally new name.  The legacy environment has webmail.domain.com.  We opted to test prior to changing our DNS entries.  So for our new environment, we are using webmail2.domain.com.  We have added a redirect to the legacy boxes for the 2003 mailboxes.  The redirect works to the legacy boxes using a new URL (which will eventually become the legacy name during coexistence - mail.domain.com ---which is the webmail.domain.com server).

The redirect works, but the users are prompted to login twice.  They login to the 2010 OWA and the redirect displays the 2003 OWA login page.  I would like single sign on.  Another issue is that even when testing the login, it errors out and says that the user can't be authenticated.  Is it that the redirect points to a name that hasn't been added to IIS?

Forms Based Authentication is enabled on the 2003 servers as well.

I hope I explained it well enough.  Essentially, we are trying to test the 2010 environment in a production environment prior to changing the DNS entries and changing certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have manually created a redirect on the CAS remove it.  Exchange 2010 CAS will automatically redirect a user to the correct OWA page based on the Mailbox type (legacy, User).  You want to configure the "Exchange2003Url" on the OWA Virtual directory.  This tells OWA what URL to send Users to if their mailbox still exists on the Exchange 2003 servers.

Also note that setting it up in this way will allow the Exchange 2010 CAS to pass the authentication form across to the Exchange 2010 Front End server.  This will ensure users do not have to re-authenticate once redirected.

Get-owavirtualdirectory | fl name,Exchange2003Url,RedirectType

Set-owavirtualdirectory -exchange2003Url "https://webmail.domain.com/exchange"

Comment: I actually used that command in the EMS to point to the new legacy URL.  The problem is not that the redirect doesn't work, it does.  The problem is that the 2003 OWA logon page comes up and won't authenticate users.  I can literally type in the new URL and get the 2003 OWA-- still can't logon.  I'm not sure if it's because we have yet to actually rename the legacy environment totally.  It's still in charge and is still webmail.domain.com.  The redirect goes to mail.domain.com.

Comment: **Continued... we have given the new environment webmail2.domain.com to test prior to cutting over.

Comment: If you go to https://webmail.domain.com/exchange and try to log into a mailbox on Exchange 2003 what happens?  The Exchange 2003 Front End server should still function regardless of the Exchange 2010 environment.  

Also note that if you plan to move your environment to use webmail.domain.com as your email domain you should consider setting up a new subdomain for use in coexistence.  i.e. legacy.domain.com that points to the same IP of the Exchange 2003 Front end server(s).

Comment: The 2003 FE works fine with it's original name.  I can logon with USERNAME/PASSWORD.  When we test the new name that it will be called "mail.domain.com", we get the 2003 logon page, but it won't authenticate, it sends a logon error like the USERNAME or PASSWORD is incorrect.  Which is strange since it's the same server.  That being said, the new "mail" name is a VIP.  Could the load balancer be stripping the logon credentials somehow?

Comment: Okay so to clarify then:  going to https://webmail.domain.com/exchange (ex03) works.  going to https://mail.domain.com/exchange (same ex03) does not work? These are pointing to the same internal IP? What happens when you try by IP?

Comment: No, they are different IPs and the new IP doesn't work either.  The reason they are 2 different IPs is for testing purposes.  Why they wanted to do it that way is beyond me.  It's a totally new VIP with a new IP (to be clear).  Our network guy thinks it may be a setting on the load balancer.  He's checking a few things on the F5.

Comment: so the VIP points to the 03 FE or the EX10 CAS?

Comment: 03 FE.  However, that VIP IP is the redirect from EX10 CAS.  It might be the VIP itself.  I just hear the network guy call someone asking about the F5 to open a port.  That could be the problem.

Comment: It sounds like the load balancer is where the failure is occurring.  If you can authenticate through the old url to 2003 than the server / exchange is functioning correctly.  Since you have Forms Based authentication already enabled on 03 that is not the issue.  Since the error on seems to happen (based on what I understand) when you access the 03 FE by the VIP that points to the F5 being the issue. I'd be interested to hear what the final resolution is though. As far as I can tell your Exchange setup is correct.

Comment: Okay... it was the Load Balancer.  I think they didn't have port 443 open--- I want to punch something.